# Why people use CSS vendor-prefix although the specs clearly says don't

Tags: css, autoprefixer, vendor-prefix

I wonder why everyone uses `vendor-prefix`es in their production builds although the CSS 2.1 specs clearly say:

> Authors should avoid vendor-specific extensions ([link](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/syndata.html#vendor-keywords))

And CSS 3 says:

> implementations should support both vendor-prefixed and unprefixed syntaxes for the feature. ([link](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-roadmap/#unstable-syntax))

So as far as I found out, vendor-prefixes are for addressing different behaviors across browsers for experimental features, And there is no point in copy-pasting a value for a specific CSS property and just adding different prefixes to it.

For example, I think it would be OK to write something like this:

```
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 10px 5px;
```

But why people use vendor prifix for things that are consistent across browsers, like:

```
-webkit-transition: all 4s ease;
-moz-transition: all 4s ease;
-ms-transition: all 4s ease;
-o-transition: all 4s ease;
transition: all 4s ease;
```

And why tools like `autoprifixer` are copy-pasting every property even if it doesn't have different behavior across browsers.

Comment: because many people read articles about features, those article were written when the feature was made (still experimental and need the prefixes) and they aren't updated but are well referenced. If you don't know what the code mean you *blindly* copy/paste and use it.

Comment: Thanks @TemaniAfif, But as CSS 3 says, even when features are still experimental, browsers should support them without vendor-prefixes.
So those articles should not exist in the first place.

Comment: The specification says : *Once the feature has stabilized and the implementation is updated to match interoperable behavior, support for the vendor-prefixed syntax should be removed.* --> You missed the important part which is **Once the feature has stabilized**

Comment: and read this part: https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-roadmap/#proprietary ... prefixes are allowed and will always be

Comment: The CSS3 spec you cite is relatively new advice. The vast majority of samples you see are years older. They all promoted - and caused - the proliferation of cargo cult prefixing, which is what led to the new advice in the CSS3 spec. For why multiple vendor prefixes when they all behave the same, that's because they're not *guaranteed* to be the same, they just happen to be really good at reaching that goal.

Comment: @BoltClock So in the future, we will get rid of most of vendor prefixes that we use today?

Comment: It used to be necessary. Nowadays, it's (mostly) not.

Comment: Yes, most vendors have agreed not to really use prefixes for experimental implementations of what will eventually be standardized anymore. You'll still see prefixes in their original intended form though - for non-standard vendor-specific stuff (this is why they will always be allowed as @Temani Afif says). Using prefixes for that stuff is normal and fine as long as you understand that it's browser-specific by design. But prefixes for experimental stuff are by and large a thing of the recent past.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

CSS 3 spec is newer than CSS 2.1, so let's skip what 2.1 says.

The spec says *implementations* —that refers to browsers, not stylesheets— *should* not require vendor prefixes. That's different from whether or not they *do*. Some browsers do require prefixes for some styles.

The thing is the W3C's CSS Working Group, who write the CSS spec, do not actually have power over browser developers — the browser developers have to choose to follow the spec (in part or in full). What's exciting is that more and more the main browsers are falling into line with the spec, and vendor prefixes are needed less and less.

The vendor-prefixed properties you need to provide depends on what browsers you support. Within a given browser, the requirements often vary by version. Newer versions of browsers for the most part require fewer vendor CSS properties than older versions of the same browser.

Snippets found online don't always age well. For example

```css
-webkit-transition: all 4s 
-moz-transition: all 4s ease;
-ms-transition: all 4s ease;
-o-transition: all 4s ease;
transition: all 4s ease;
```

would typically be considered overkill these days. Always check the date on bits of code found online. On SO, checking rep can help you distinguish between workable answers and best answers.

There's a whole separate question of how dropping support for old browsers related to web accessibility. Won't get into that here, but there are some people who say that choosing to only support more recent and/or popular browsers is inherently problematic.

Autoprefixer can be configured to target exactly the browsers you want to support. It adds only the vendor-specific CSS needed to meet the need you specify. By default, Autoprefixer uses the Browserlist default. With that setting, no vendor-specific code is needed to support `border-radius: 10px 5px` and `transition: all 4s ease`. You can see that by running your two rules through https://autoprefixer.github.io/, "filtered" by `> 0.5%, last 2 versions, Firefox ESR, not dead`. You can see which browsers that covers at https://browserl.ist/?q=%3E+0.5%25%2C+last+2+versions%2C+Firefox+ESR%2C+not+dead

In practice, a lot of people simply do not write vendor-specific CSS, relying on Autoprefixer built into their build tooling. For example, you might have a [Gulp](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp) or [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) setup that automatically runs your stylesheets through Autoprefixer. If that's new to you, a good starting point might be [postcss-cli](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-cli), the command line tool for PostCSS.

```sh
npm install -g postcss-cli autoprefixer
postcss my-styles.css --use autoprefixer --dir output-directory
```

Comment: So from your answer, I understood that a fully css 3 compatible browser would not require any vendor prefix to work correctly, unless for some properties that are different from the final specs. Is it correct?

Comment: I think that's a reasonable way to think about. It gets tricky because a given feature might not be stable when a particular version of a browser is released. When the feature stabilizes, the old version of the browser still expects the browser prefix. So maybe think of it like "a browser version that is fully compatible with the CSS 3 spec doesn't require prefixes for any properties that are stable at the time that version of the browser is released."

Comment: But the spec says that the browser should support the unprefixed syntax alongside with the prifixed one, even when the property is not stable yet.

Comment: "When exposing such a standards-track unstable feature to the Web in a production release, implementations should support both vendor-prefixed and unprefixed syntaxes for the feature. Once the feature has stabilized and the implementation is updated to match interoperable behavior, support for the vendor-prefixed syntax should be removed."

Comment: Yep, and what we're seeing is the major browsers taking that "should" more seriously, and the need for vendor prefixes is becoming less and less. Maybe what's confusing is that the w3c's CSS working group doesn't actually have any power over browser developers. The remarkable thing isn't that sometimes prefixes are still needed, it's that browsers are coming into line with the spec, which is great news

Comment: Now I get that, thankyou so much. Would you consider adding this point to your answer?